# Nautilus search provider Gnome-Shell Activities / Overview

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 13.04, search

I do not get search results for files in the Gnome Shell overview except for files that are placed in my Home folder. Currently, I am using Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 with GS 3.8 from the Gnome3 PPA, but have not added the Gnome3 Staging PPA yet (seems to be risky).

In the tracker GUI configuration my favourites (Downloads, Documents, et cetera) are marked as recursive. Gnome Documents also indexes and displays files in subfolders properly. I've checked dconf as well and everything seems to be fine:

```
['&DESKTOP', '&PICTURES', '&DOCUMENTS', '&DOWNLOAD', '&MUSIC', '&VIDEOS']
```

Only the Home folder is marked as `index-single-directories`:

```
['$HOME']
```

Could there be a problem caused by my language settings? 
I've read about issues concerning tracker in regard to language settings, so I already cleared my tracker DB and restarted scanning, but still no results.
Whenever I move a file to my Home folder, it will be displayed instantly. What can I do about that?

Comment: Can you check and verify these things:
Nautilus version?
gnome-control-center aka System Settings or Settings in 3.8>Search>Settings(icon at bottom right)?

Comment: Nautilus is 3.8.1 (1:3.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1), 
gnome-control-center is still 3.6.3 (1:3.6.3-0ubuntu24)

Comment: What are the settings of the Control Center>Search>Settings>Advanced(bottom right)?

Comment: The search option is not implemented in 3.6.3.

Comment: Oh I see now. That could be part of the problem I suppose. On another recent question someone said the only way they could get everything in 3.8 working correctly they used the staging ppa. I'd say it's worth testing but you'd probably want to make a backup first. Or, you could try to just add the repos and only update gnome-control-center

Comment: I've added the Staging Repository on another machine a couple of days ago (and of course upgraded the packages via dist-upgrade). I let the tracker complete its indexing, but sadly ... still no files showing up. Again, if files are located directly in the home folder, they immediately show up.

Comment: @l300lvl If you post your comment as a question, then I'd mark it as solved - some points for your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug, there is a "fix" for nautilus 6.3
https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus/+bug/1076232

Good luck, sorry for my english