# Gnome shell overview search does not search directories indexed by tracker

Tags: gnome, nautilus, search, tracker

Running a very recent install of GNOME Shell 3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04. the command-line tracker search tools work very well but the overview search in the GNOME Shell does not search the filesystem. Similarly to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292190/nautilus-search-provider-gnome-shell-activities-overview) post, it only searches my home directory, regardless of the indexing preferences set through the tracker GUI or dconf. At a certain point it would search another file as well, a random one several levels down in my documents folder, but no others, and looking at permissions etc. did not give me any clues. It has since stopped being listed in the search results.

Since the other search functions work fine, as well as the search when I log out and into the Unity desktop, it may not be a problem with tracker but with however the GNOME overview search GUI talks to tracker. I have removed and reinstalled tracker, etc. to no avail. Still haven't messed with Nautilus much, failed to successfully perform the 'bug' fix in that above link. At the end of my skills. Thanks!!

Comment: found a semi-fix using this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/783/tracker-search-provider/ 
useful extension. for me, it wouldn't install from the gnome extension website, so i followed the instructions on the github link and found that the note to install GObject introspection (gir1.2-tracker package) was critical. once installed, i could install this extension through the extension site. though i suspect this is different from the default overview search, this extension searches the filesystem effectively.

Comment: The current version of that extension no longer works. At least for the time being, and on 18.04. Perhaps because it depends on tracker-needle. Which got removed. And the extension isn't being maintained anymore.